# How to show data in multi select using Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, edit, multi-select

i would like to show data that saved before in a multi select. I have a product table that is connected one to many to a promo detail table, and I want to display the products that have been previously selected then the user can edit it if necessary.
Here is my **Product model**

```
    protected $table = 'm_product';

    protected $primaryKey ='id';

    protected $fillable = ['kode','id_kategori', 'foto_product', 'product', 'stok', 'stok_opname', 'ppn', 'harga', 'deskripsi', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'changed_by', 'updated_at', 'delete'];
    
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function kategori() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Kategori', 'id_kategori');
    }

    public function stok() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Stok', 'id');
    }

    public function promodetail() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\DetailPromo', 'id');
    }
```

and here is my **Promo detail model**

```
protected $table = 'tb_promo_detail';

protected $primaryKey ='id';

protected $fillable = ['id_promo','id_kategori', 'id_product', 'det_potongan', 'det_jumlah_potongan'];

public $timestamps = false;

public function promo() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Promo', 'id_promo');
}

public function produk() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Produk', 'id_product');
}
```

Here is my blade.php

```
<div class="form-group row " id="inputbarang">
    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">Barang</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <select class="form-control m-select2" width="500px" id="kt_select2_1" name="id_product[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        @foreach($produk as $p)
                        <option value="{{ $p->id }}" {{ $p->id == $detpromo->id_product ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $p->product }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
```

and here is my controller

```
$promo = Promo::find($id);

$detpromo = DetailPromo::where('id_promo', $id)->pluck('id_product')->toArray();

$produk = Produk::where('m_product.delete', 0)
        ->where('id_kategori', 1)
        ->orWhere('id_kategori', 2)
        ->orWhere('id_kategori', 3)->get();


$kategori = Kategori::where('delete', 0)->pluck('id');

return view('promoharirayaedit', ['promo' => $promo, 'detpromo' => $detpromo, 'produk' => $produk, 'kategori' => $kategori]);
```

i dont know how to solve this, please help.. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I did not get the question

Comment: i want to show the products data in a multiselect from the database. These data will shown in a multi select option in edit view. But i dont know how to solve that @sta